# Add metadata tag to teradata objects

Tags: sql, metadata, teradata, database-metadata

I have several stored procedures in Teradata that I wish to label. Therefore, I'm looking for a way to add metadata to an object in Teradata. I've been looking into Teradata's [Data Dictionary](https://dbmstutorials.com/teradata/teradata_data_dictionary_queries.html), but it seems the only way is to add labels as comments.

Is there a better way to tag, label and/or identify stored procedures in Teradata?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *add metadata*, can you show an example?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean [query bands](https://docs.teradata.com/r/rgAb27O_xRmMVc_aQq2VGw/sME3hVgEFSOZHQh_qyV8_Q)?

Answer (score 1):

Comment placement

```
comment on procedure <database_name>.<procedure_name> 'test procedure';
```

Comment retrieval

```
comment on procedure <database_name>.<procedure_name>;
```